# Grafana / Graphite - the time metric was in some state

Tags: graphite, grafana, metric, downtime

I have metric "monitor.status" with values 0 and 1. 0 indicating service down state and 1 - up state.

I'd like to render downtime period in seconds in Single stat panel. How to get the time metric was in 0 state and render it?

Example:

```
Value - Timestamp (just h:m to simplify)
1 - 05:00
1 - 05:05
0 - 05:07
0 - 05:09
1 - 05:11
0 - 05:16
0 - 05:18

Here metric was is "0" state for 4 minutes. This is the value I'd like to get.
```

Do you have any suggestions how to track downtime period correctly in graphite?

Comment: what does that "0" state for 4 minutes mean? could you provide details? What is your query and what you are expecting/

Comment: 0 and 1 - just a metric values.
I'd like to know how long metric was in "0" value (period), in this example it's 4 minutes (05:07 - 05:09 and 05:16 - 05:18 , 4 minutes in total)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, it can be e.g.

```
integral(divideSeries(monitor.status, countSeries(monitor.status)))
```

Example:
If monitor.status is `[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]`
then
`countSeries(monitor.status) = [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]` and
`divideSeries(monitor.status, countSeries(monitor.status)) = 
[0,0,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,0.1]`
and `integral()` of series above will give you `0.6` at the end of result which stat will show to you.
Just do not forget to change `Max data points` of stat panel to 1, otherwise, you'll get less than 0.6

Comment: Ah, and you should set "Time range" for stat panel for a timespan of your SLA calculation period.

Comment: I've edited initial description. What I'm trying to get is the duration metric was in some state, based on it timestamps.